# Divergence theorem in volume integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

We have a partial differential equation
 \begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot (p_1^2\nabla\alpha)=0\,.
\end{equation}

Question: from this equation how can I write the following condition?

\begin{equation}
\int_\Omega\alpha\nabla \cdot(p_1^2\nabla\alpha)=
\int_{\partial\Omega}\alpha p_1^2 n\cdot\nabla\alpha
-\int_\Omega p_1^2(\nabla\alpha)^2=0 \,.
\end{equation}
$p_1$ and $\alpha$ are position dependent variable.

Comment: This is the generalization of partial integration to volume integrals.

Comment: It looks very familiar to me, the construction that is, but might I inquire, what are p and alpha?

Comment: P and $\alpha$ are position dependent variable.

Comment: @ComplexGuy $p_1^2\nabla \alpha $ is a vector, so $\nabla(p_1^2\nabla \alpha ) $ makes no sense, do you mean $ div(p_1^2\nabla \alpha ) $ instead ?

Comment: Yes sorry my bad I'm editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this is an application of the [Divergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem), assuming everything is smooth:
$$
\int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot F  = \int_{\partial \Omega} F\cdot n\,dS,
$$

Let $F = \alpha p \nabla \alpha$, where $p = p_1^2$. The product rule reads for a vector $v$ and a scalar $\phi$:
$$
\nabla \cdot (\phi v) = \nabla \phi \cdot v + \phi\nabla \cdot v, 
$$
therefore we have:

$$
\int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot (\alpha p \nabla \alpha) = \int_{\Omega} \Big(\alpha \nabla \cdot (p \nabla \alpha) + p \nabla \alpha \cdot \nabla \alpha \Big) = \int_{\partial \Omega} \alpha p \nabla \alpha\cdot n\,dS,
$$
and this is
$$
\int_{\Omega}\alpha \nabla \cdot (p \nabla \alpha) = \int_{\partial \Omega} \alpha p (\nabla \alpha\cdot n)\,dS - \int_{\Omega}p \nabla \alpha \cdot \nabla \alpha ,
$$
rewrite $\nabla \alpha \cdot \nabla \alpha  = |\nabla \alpha|^2$, and by the original equation $\nabla \cdot (p \nabla \alpha) = 0$, the left hand side of above vanishes, hence we have:
$$
\int_{\partial \Omega} \alpha p (\nabla \alpha\cdot n)\,dS - \int_{\Omega}p |\nabla \alpha|^2 = 0 .
$$

---

Or you can just memorize the integration by parts formula derived from the divergence theorem:
$$
\int_{\Omega} u\nabla \cdot v = -\int_{\Omega} \nabla u\cdot v + \int_{\partial \Omega} u(v\cdot n)\,dS.
$$